# Comparision of the timestamp in procedure not working

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, timestamp

I have written a following query in my procedure which is not inserting the records in the `TEST` table. The `KPI definition` table has the following record:

```
KPI_DEF_ID  KPI_FREQUENCY KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT  EVENT_ID
1000136     30            MINUTE                10028   
1000137     50            MINUTE                10028
```

I have a application in which user want to get the records depending on the timestamp. So user can enter in the application to get the records for example older than 30 min and newer than 24 hour. And the timestamp is changable. The older than timestamp comes from the `KPI DEFINITION` table and which is stored in the column `KPI_FREQUENCY` and `KPI_FREQUENCY_UNIT` and it can be changabler. And the newer than timestamp is fixed and i stored it in varaible `LAST_OLDER_VAL` and `LAST_OLDER_VAL_UNIT`. I used the insert using select query to store the records in table but its not working.

```
         create or replace PROCEDURE "EXT_TEST" AS 

LAST_WF_ID Number := 0;
--LAST_UNIT NUMBER:=10;
--LAST_UNIT_VAL VARCHAR2(20);
LAST_OLDER_VAL NUMBER := 24;
LAST_OLDER_VAL_UNIT VARCHAR2(10) := 'HOUR';

CURSOR WF_WORKFLOW_CUR IS
Select KPI_DEF_ID,KPI_FREQUENCY,KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT,EVENT_ID,BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_ID FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION where EVENT_ID=10028;
BEGIN

--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST_UNIT - ' || LAST_UNIT);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST_UNIT_VAL - ' || LAST_UNIT_VAL);

-- removed, retrieve  a new START_ID from source first, don't use the last id.
--SELECT LAST_TASK_ID INTO LAST_WF_ID FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_WF_WORKFLOW';

FOR WF_WORKFLOW_ROW IN WF_WORKFLOW_CUR
LOOP

--select MIN(ID) INTO LAST_WF_ID from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF where WF.START_DATE > sysdate - numtodsinterval ( WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQUENCY, WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT );

Insert into TEST(ID,NAME,SUBSCRIPTION_ID,START_DATE,STATUS_ID,ACCOUNT_ID,END_DATE)
Select DISTINCT(WF.ID),WF.NAME,WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,WF.START_DATE,WF.STATUS_ID,WF.ACCOUNT_ID,WF.END_DATE
from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF where WF.STATUS_ID = 0 and WF.NAME = 'SIGNUP_MOBILE_PRE_PAID'
and WF.START_DATE > SYSDATE - numtodsinterval ( LAST_OLDER_VAL, LAST_OLDER_VAL_UNIT
and WF.START_DATE < SYSDATE - numtodsinterval ( WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQUENCY, WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT ));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQUENCY - ' || WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQUENCY);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT - ' || WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT);

END LOOP;

END EXT_TEST;
```

Comment: What do u mean by not working? Are you getting any error? Or incorrect result?

Comment: I am not getting any error and the records are not inserting into the TEST table. The problem is in my select query condition where i am comparing and thats why its not working.

Comment: Consider to use data type `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` instead of `FREQUENCY` and `FREQ_TIME_UNIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently looking for a start date that is older than 24 hours and newer than 30 minutes. Which is impossible, and not what you stated you needed, so that isn't what you mean really. Looks like you just have your `<` and `>` comparisons the wrong way around:

```
...
and WF.START_DATE > SYSDATE - numtodsinterval ( LAST_OLDER_VAL, LAST_OLDER_VAL_UNIT )
and WF.START_DATE < SYSDATE - numtodsinterval ( WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQUENCY, WF_WORKFLOW_ROW.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT );
```

Not directly relevant, but I'm not sure why you're using a loop for this, rather than a single `insert ... select` which joins `WF_WORKFLOW_CUR` and `WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL`. Or really why you'd use a stored procedure at all.

Comment: Hello Alex i changed my question and used your condition but getting error missing right parenthesis. And i am using loop because in the KPI_DEFINITION table you can see we have different kpi_frequency and kpi_frequency_unit for the same event_id and i want to consider these different timestamp for the same event.And there can be more timestamp for the same event_id. I can also use join as you said instead of loop but the logic will be same right and in that case will it consider both these timestamp for the same event_id?

Comment: @Rahul - why have you changed the question? Yes, I lost the right parenthesis on the first line of my answer; but you've also added an extra one on the second line. (I removed a redundant set, but not quite successfully...)

Comment: I am using procedure because i have few more things done in this procedure and which is executing but i stuck at this point. Using loop its working now but as you said if i dont use loop and use join then will it work if i will be having more than 1 timestamp defined for the same event_id ?

Comment: Sorry i just changed the procedure in my question but that procedure is working now i have fixed the parenthesis problem.

Comment: @Rahul - yes; you'll get duplicates either way though, surely - you'd get two records for everything between 24 hours and 50 minutes ago. and one record for everything between 50 and 30 minutes ago. A join would still be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Ohh ok for removing duplicate i am using NOT EXISTS in the same select query and checking in my TEST table whether the records already exists and then adding new records. I will try to use join then and check the performance